# Predict the next location based on the previous days data using lstm

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, prediction

Based on the 10 days of the data I need to predict the 11th-day location of the user. Example of my input is in [this link](https://ufile.io/onvco3g6)

The dataset contains: 
200,000 users with  1550 random location points and 10days of history for each user

```
from datetime import datetime
from random import seed

import pandas as pd

seed(150)

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', delimiter=';')
df = df.iloc[:-1,:]
df = df.drop(columns='tslot')

def normalize_cols(df, cols):
for col in df.columns:
print(col, df[col].max(), df[col].min())
df[col] = (df[col] - df[col].min())/(df[col].max() - df[col].min())
return df

df = normalize_cols(df, ['slot', 'location', 'user'])
df.to_csv('cleaned_data.csv', index=False)
```

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('cleaned_data.csv')
train_x = df[['slot', 'user']].copy()
train_y = df[['tower']].copy().values
train_x = train_x.values.reshape((train_x.shape[0], 1, train_x.shape[1]))
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(40))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=25,  verbose=2, shuffle=True)
model.save('5g_tower.h5')
del model
model = load_model('5g_tower.h5')
## Prediction
def get_tower_number(model, slot, user): 
## normalize input slot, tower, user
slot = ((slot - 0)*1.0) / ((95.0 - 0.0)*1.0)
user = ((user - 1)*1.0) / ((2.0 - 1.0)*1.0)

## get a slot for next 15 mins
res = model.predict(np.array([[[slot, user]]]))

## de-normalize that tower
return int(res[0][0] * ((1354.0 - 9.0)*1.0) + 9.0)

print(get_tower_number(model, 4, 1))
```

But failed to predict the location of the user for the 11th day. The output I got is wrong compared to the required output.
The example of the output is given in [this link](https://ufile.io/im6ugyw8). How to implement individual model rather than the global model in this system?
The example output should be the 11th day:

```
     User   location   slot
      1        145       0




      1         94       95
      2         562       0

      2         583       95
```

The actual dataset contains a total of 350,000 users

Comment: What do you mean with "failed"? No output, wrong output? You should really quote (some of) the example output here, rather than directing us to an ad-infested, short lived file hosting service.

Comment: Please fix indentation in your code. Do you have these curly brackets (1st and last line) in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the model implementation, you're missing activation function for every Dense block, so keras is applying linear activation. 
You can modify that using:

```
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```